# AngularJS - How to disable access from URL

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with routes :

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'orders/list',
        controller: OrderController
    });   

    $routeProvider.when('/editOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'addOrder/editOrder',
        controller: ActionController
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
```

I want to navigate to the edit page only when a button is clicked, but this definition allows access via url from browser also. Is it possible to disable access via url ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Navigate to edit page without context(selected item before) make no sense.

Comment: Of course it makes sense. But the URL of the edit page should be something like `/editOrder/{orderId}`. That's what's missing from your configuration.

Comment: Right, this is also correct, but don't protect url access. I want to protect against manually access and editing unauthorized items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$routeChangeStart` event to implement custom logic on route to be changed and veto navigation depending on some condition/permission. In the following example you can navigate to `/edit` route only if you have granted permissions, which you can grant or revoke using `PermissionsService` service. In the following example you can try to navigate via direct link and see that you are redirected to default route, and when you click Edit button you are redirected to the relevant route. Also, if you are on `/edit` route and make browser back and forward, you can notice that you can't go back to `/edit` route.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<a href="#/edit">Edit</a>
<div ng-view></div>
<button ng-click="edit()">Edit</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'OrderController'
    });   

    $routeProvider.when('/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'edit.html',
        controller: 'ActionController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
  }]).
  run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'PermissionsService', function($rootScope, $location, PermissionsService) {
    $rootScope.edit = function() {
      PermissionsService.setPermission('edit', true);
      $location.path('/edit');
    };
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
      if (next.templateUrl === "edit.html") {
        if(!PermissionsService.getPermission('edit')) {
          $location.path('/');
        }
        PermissionsService.setPermission('edit', false);
      }
    });
  }]).
  service('PermissionsService', [function() {
    var permissions = {
      edit: false
    };
    this.setPermission = function(permission, value) {
      permissions[permission] = value;
    }
    this.getPermission = function(permission) {
      return permissions[permission] || false;
    }
  }]).
  controller('OrderController', [function() {}]).
  controller('ActionController', [function() {}]);
```

**Live example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7lx387td4xlZZxUlFvfM?p=preview).**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resolve` property and set some variable on an external service:

```
App.factory('editMode', function(){
  var editMode = false;
  return {
    getEditMode: function(){ return editMode; },
    setEditMode: function(edit) { editMode = edit; }
  }
}
```

And then on the route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/editOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'addOrder/editOrder',
        controller: ActionController,
        resolve: function(editMode){
           if(!editMode.getEditMode()) {
              $location.path( "/" );
           }
        }
    });
```